# How do I find the smaller width of two values with different units in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a website where the maximum width is 500px, but if the window size is smaller (e.g. the user is on mobile, etc.), I want the width to just be 90%. How do I make it find the smaller value between 500px and 90%? This is what I've tried:

```css
element {
  width: 90%, 500px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `max-width`, `min-width`, and `width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width:min`...

> The min() CSS function lets you set the smallest (most negative) value from a list of comma-separated expressions as the value of a CSS property value.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min())

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  background: red;
  width: min(90%, 500px); 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyzQJjr)